# Viewing firebase storage dms files

Tags: firebase

I'm on a Mac. What application can open the dms files you download directly from the console?

Preview doesn't work, and I also tried Unarchiver per the following link, but no go:

https://fileinfo.com/extension/dms

Comment: Just a note that this question is off topic for this site; *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow* and you should stick with programming related questions. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I am not sure the Firebase tag is appriate as it seems the question has nothing to do with Firebase and the Firebase Console usually exports .txt files or stores .jpg or .png type files.

Comment: See my answer. I hope that helps you @Latcie

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so it turns out that you only need change the extension. In my case it was from .dms to .jpg.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to download the **Image** with `DownloadURL` which are stored in **Firebase Storage** but you're getting a file with `dms` extension instead of actual `image` file. The problem is that you're not providing `Content Type` of `Meta Data` while uploading it.

By doing this, the `type` of the image is `application/octet-stream`.

[image: Without Content Type]

Now if you download the file with `Download URL`, you'll get file with `dms` extension.

[image: File with dms extension]

If you want to download the actual image then just add the `Content Type` of `Meta Data` and pass it in [putData](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/StorageReference#/c:objc(cs)FIRStorageReference(im)putData:metadata:completion:) method.

```
let metaDataForImage = StorageMetadata()
metaDataForImage.contentType = “image/jpeg"
```

Now see the image in **Firebase Storage**. The `type` of the image is `image/jpeg`.

[image: With Content Type]

Just try downloading the image with `DownloadURL`. The file will be downloaded with `image(jpeg) extension` instead of `dms extension`. That's it!

**Sample Code Snippet** :

```
       let metaDataForImage = StorageMetadata()
       metaDataForImage.contentType = "image/jpeg"

       storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: metaDataForImage, completion: { (metadata, error) in
       print("Image uploaded to Firebase successfully")

                //MARK: - Uploading Image URL
                self.storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                    if url != nil {
                        guard let profileImageURL = url?.absoluteString else { return }
                        FirebaseDatabaseReference.users(uid: userUID).reference().updateChildValues(["profileImageURL": profileImageURL], withCompletionBlock: { (error, reference) in
                            if error == nil {
                                print("URL Uploaded to Firebase DB")
                            } else {
                                print("Failed to upload Image URL to Firebase DB")
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })

            })
```