# How do I load a Google Cloud Storage Firebase export into BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery

I have a simple, single collection in Firestore, a museum visitor name and date with some other fields.

I successfully ran a gcloud export:
gcloud beta firestore export gs://climatemuseumexhibition2019gov.appspot.com --collection-ids=visitors

and the collection is now sitting in a bucket in Cloud Storage.

I tried downloading the data, which appears to be in several chunks, but it's in .dms format and I have no idea what that is.

Also, I've successfully linked BigQuery to my firestore project but don't see the collection, and I don't see the Cloud Storage object at all.

I gather the idea is create a Dataset from the Cloud Storage, then create a Table from the dataset. I'd appreciate specific details on how to do that.

I've read the manuals and they are opaque on this topic, so I'd appreciate some first hand experience. Thank you.

Comment: Did you follow [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore)?  If so, where did you get stuck?  If you can't see the cloud storage object, is your cloud storage bucket and dataset in the same location?

Comment: Could you please add more details on your case? What is the exact result of the export? What other type of fields do you have in your database? Please provide as much information as you can in order for community members to be able to help you solve your issue. In case you have an image field in your collection maybe [this could help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47859860/viewing-firebase-storage-dms-files).